# Create a service with generic parameters in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have this service which I am injecting into other services via DI, where I need to convert objects returned from one layer of an API application to another.

I am initializing it like this:

```
ICommonInterface<SourceObj, DestObj> _obj;
```

but if the source and destination are lists then I would have to inject another object of this service

```
ICommonInterface<List<SourceObj>, List<DestObj>> _obj;
```

and same if the conversion is other way around or entirely different.

Is there a way to further abstract the list part so that I do not need to initialize two objects of the same service?

What I want to do is initialize it like this

```
ICommonInterface<GenericSource, GenericDest> _obj;
```

so when I have multiple conversions I would not have to initialize multiple times. Only when it is being used in a function the type of source and dest would be decided.

This is the definition of this function.

```
public class CommonService<SourceResultSet, DestinationResultSet> : ICommonInterface<SourceResultSet, DestinationResultSet>
{
    public GenericResultSet<DestinationResultSet> convertResultSet<DestinationResultSet>(GenericResultSet<SourceResultSet> sourceResultSet,IMapper _mapper)
    {
        GenericResultSet<DestinationResultSet> returnResultSet = new() {
            status = sourceResultSet.status,
            message = sourceResultSet.message,
            resultSet = _mapper.Map<DestinationResultSet>(sourceResultSet.resultSet)
        };

        return returnResultSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: "_where I need to convert objects returned from one layer of an API application to another._" - Only use generics for this if you can _guarantee_ that the generic-constraints will 100% accurately reflect the service's ability to convert objects. If you can't do that, then don't use generics here. For example, consder what should happen if I did something nonsensical like `new CommonService<SqlConnection,FileInfo>`.